# jquery get elements by name

Tags: jquery

Hi there can I get code to get a list dropdown of elements in  a form by name
and also rename them at the same time
thanks

Comment: Correct (or any, for that matter) punctuation is preferred, thank you. Also your question text does not match the title well. What do you mean by "rename"? Change the value of the `name` attribute?

Comment: Hi there can you please be much much much more specific about what you want and maybe what you have tried already and where you're stuck and maybe also use some punctuation thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
jQuery('#myForm select[name=foo]').each(function () { 
    jQuery(this).attr('name', 'bar') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the attribute selector

```
$('td[name=myname]') // matches exactly 'myname'

$('td[name^=myname]') // matches those that begin with 'myname'
```

Answer (score 0):

Get values of each drop-down list with common name using jquery?

```js
function checkId(){
    $.each($("select[name='selectCtrl']"), function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id') +" : "+ $(this).val());
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select class="form-control" id="select1" name="selectCtrl">
       <option value="1">one</option>
       <option value="2">two</option>
       <option value="3">three</option>         
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="select2" name="selectCtrl">
       <option value="4">four</option>
       <option value="5">five</option>
       <option value="6">six</option>         
    </select>

    <button onclick="checkId()" >check Id</button>

</body>
</html>
```